# Which SQL query execute faster?

Tags: mysql

I've a doubt on performance /speed of executing query.

1. `SELECT * FROM <MY_TABLE> WHERE COLUMN="A"`
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROWCOUNTS, * FROM <MY_TABLE> WHERE COLUMN="A";`

Which query will execute faster?

Comment: Why don't you time both queries a couple of times and see the results yourself?

Comment: Logically I'd have to say the 1st one, there's less overhead.  Though if Column "A" is indexed they will roughly be equivalent as the index knows it's total count down each tree.

Comment: @Shadow I've tested both the queries are getting differ by milli seconds. To conclude that only i've asked in here.

Comment: Why do bother with differences in millisecs at all? Besides, your question cannot be answered based on the information you provided. We can apply common sense just as @xQbert did, but cannot go any further than that.

Comment: Specifiying columns besides using "*" should be faster.